# Sort array columns based upon sum

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose I have an array as such:

```
np.array([1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0.],
       [8., 0., 8.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2.]])
```

With column[0] summing to 16, column[1] to 6 and column[2] to 10.

How do I efficiently in Numpy re-arrange the array by column value greatest to least? In the above example, column[0] would remain in place and column[1] and column[2] would switch positions.

Comment: Also can try `np.array(list(zip(*sorted(zip(*arr), key=sum,reverse=True))))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `sum` along `axis=0` and use `argsort` then reverse the array and use:

```
a[:,np.argsort(a.sum(axis=0))[::-1]]

array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 4.],
       [8., 8., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `np.sum` and `np.argsort` you can achieve this as follows:

```
x = np.array([[1., 1., 0.],[0., 4., 0.],[8., 0., 8.],[0., 0., 0.],[5., 0., 0.],[2., 2., 2.]])
x[:, np.argsort(-np.sum(x, 0))]
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Comment: `-np.sum(x, 0))` is simpler than flipping the indices in the end. nice.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the last two columns is done this way:

```
a = np.array([[1., 1., 0.],
             [0., 4., 0.],
             [8., 0., 8.],
             [0., 0., 0.],
             [5., 0., 0.],
             [2., 2., 2.]])

result = a[:, [0, 2, 1]]
```

So, what you need is to calculate those indexes `[0, 2, 1]` based on column sums.

This gets you the sums of all columns:

```
a.sum(axis=0)  # array([16.,  7., 10.])
```

and from that, you get the indices for sorting:

```
np.argsort(np.array([16.,  7., 10.]))   # [1, 2, 0]
```

You need to flip it to get the highest-to-lowest order:

```
np.flip([1, 2, 0])   # [0, 2, 1]
```

So, all together, it is:

```
result = a[:, np.flip(np.argsort(a.sum(axis=0)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([[1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 4., 0.],
                [8., 0., 8.],
                [0., 0., 0.],
                [5., 0., 0.],
                [2., 2., 2.]])

perm = np.flip(np.argsort(np.sum(arr, axis=0)))
result = a[:, perm]
```

Get the sums; then get the permutation (array of indices) which sorts the sums. `argsort` sorts in ascending order, so reverse the permutation so we get indices from highest sum to lowest. Finally, reorder the original array by the same permutation.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar: Right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def main():
    a = np.array([[1., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 4., 0.],
                 [8., 0., 8.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [5., 0., 0.],
                 [2., 2., 2.]])
    col_sum = np.sum(a, axis=0)
    sort_index = np.argsort(-col_sum) # index sort in descending order
    out_matrix = a[:, sort_index]
    print(out_matrix)
```

I think that a new instance (out_matrix) is necessary because you can't really switch columns inplace.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd, numpy as np
>>> arr=np.array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0.],
       [8., 0., 8.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2.]])
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(arr)
>>> df.sort_index(axis=1).values
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 8.,  0.,  8.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>>
```

Comment: Here is a loop which is executed in python, rather than in numpy: `sorted(df.columns.tolist(),key=lambda x: df[x].sum(),reverse=True)`. That is not efficient. The whole point of using numpy is not to make loops in python.

Comment: @zvone Edited mine, much cleaner